# AngularJS - injection error after minification

Tags: angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I get injection error after minification. I can't find what is wrong with this code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">

  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak>
<div ng-controller="SideNavController as vm">
<p>
    {{vm.name}}
</p>
</div>


  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- <script src="layout/main-container.controller.js"></script> -->
 <!-- My application  -->
 <script src="/scripts/app.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script after concat and minification
/scripts/app.min.js

```
!function()
{"use strict";function n(){}
angular.module("app").config(n)}(),
function(){angular.module("app",["ngMaterial","ngSanitize","ngAnimate","app.layout"])}()
,function(){"use strict";function n(){console.log("run app")}
angular.module("app").run(n)}(),
function(){"use strict";function n(){var n=this;n.name="SideNavController"}
angular.module("app.layout",[]).controller("SideNavController",n)}();
```

I get this error:

```
angular.js:2082 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=app(…)
angular.js:4640 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A189%3A487)(…)
```

original sidenav.controller.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict'; // ECMAScript version 5

  angular.module('app.layout', [])
  .controller('SideNavController', SideNavController);

  /* @ngInject */
  function SideNavController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = "SideNavController";
  }


})();
```

app.module.js

```
(function(){
  angular.module('app', [
    /* AngularJS modules */
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngAnimate',
      /* app.feature modules */
    'app.layout'
    /* cross.app modules */

  ]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to change the order of minified functions in app.min.js.

```
!function()
{
  angular.module("app",["ngMaterial","ngSanitize","ngAnimate","app.layout"])
}(),
function(){
  "use strict";function n(){}
angular.module("app").config(n)
}(),

function()
{
  "use strict";
  function n(){
    console.log("run app")
  }
angular.module("app").run(n)
}(),

function()
{
  "use strict";
  function n(){var n=this;n.name="SideNavController"}
  angular.module("app.layout",[]).controller("SideNavController",n)

}();
```